# Polymer iron-autogrow-textarea display count of signs

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I wonder if there is any way to display count of signs typed in iron-autogrow-textarea? If yes, how can I do it?

I tried this solution.

Javascript function:

```
countChars: function (countFrom, displayTo) {
      var len = document.getElementById(countFrom).value.length;
      document.getElementById(displayTo).innerHTML.len;
    }
```

Polymer component:

```
<iron-autogrow-textarea id="textarea"
                            placeholder="Enter description ..." rows="1" max-rows="4"
                            maxlength="500"
                            onkeyup="countChars('textarea','charcount');"
                            onkeydown="countChars('textarea','charcount');"
                            onmouseout="countChars('textarea','charcount');">
    </iron-autogrow-textarea>
<span id="charcount">0</span>/500
```

What am I doing wrong or how should I do it so that it will works?

Answer (score 1):

#### Bugs:

1. Your Javascript does not write anything. The last line is:

   `document.getElementById(displayTo).innerHTML.len;`

   when you probably meant:

   `document.getElementById(displayTo).innerHTML = len;`
2. You're not using the correct syntax for Polymer event binding. To bind event handlers to a Polymer element, use [`on-{eventname}="handlerName"`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html#annotated-listeners). For `keyup`, you would use `on-keyup` (not `onkeyup`). Unlike `onkeyup` values, the value for `on-keyup` cannot be arbitrary Javascript code. Instead, it must be the name of a function defined in your Polymer element.

#### Inefficiencies:

1. You're querying the document with `document.getElementById('foo')` when you could use Polymer's [automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding) instead (i.e., `Polymer.$.foo`).
2. You're trying to bind both `keyup` and `keydown`, which would cause your handler to be called twice for every key press. The `mouseout` binding seems unnecessary as well.

#### Working example:

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ledakanase/edit?html,output)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Polymer Imports -->
    <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
    <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="iron-autogrow-textarea/iron-autogrow-textarea.html">   
</head>

<body>
  <my-input></my-input>

  
  <dom-module id="my-input">
    <template>
      <iron-autogrow-textarea id="textarea"
                              placeholder="Enter description ..." rows="1" max-rows="4"
                              maxlength="500"
                              on-keyup="_countChars"
      ></iron-autogrow-textarea>
      <span id="charcount">0</span>/500
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-input',

        _countChars: function() {
          this.$.charcount.textContent = this.$.textarea.value.length;
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Try `paper-textarea` instead:

You might find [`<paper-textarea>`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-textarea) useful, as it already implements the [character counter](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-input?active=paper-textarea#property-charCounter):

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qetoxefivo/edit?html,output)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Polymer Imports -->
    <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
    <link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-textarea.html">
</head>

<body>
  <paper-textarea placeholder="Enter description ..."
               maxlength="500"
               max-rows="4"
               char-counter              
  ></paper-textarea>
</body>

</html>
```